# Repeat alarm every 20 minutes in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'd like to repeat an alarm every 20 minutes.
So I tried:

manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

AlarmReceiver.class

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                showNotification(context, "text", "text", intent2);

                Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
                r.play();
        }

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void showNotification(Context context, String title, String body, Intent intent) { 

... 

} 

   }
```

and in my main activity:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1200);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

It is working only the first time. I'd like to keep it repeating even when the app is not opening, any ideas?

Comment: You are using `alarmMgr.set`. It sets the alarm once and doesn't repeat itself. To repeat the alarm, you need to use `alarmMgr.setRepeating` and pass 20 minutes as the interval time. Just remember, the alarms won't be delivered exactly 20 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with KitKat (API 19), alarms are all *inexact*, meaning the system will batch alarms around similar times together.  If you need exact timing, there are different APIs to call.  Further complicating things, starting with Marshmallow, Android introduced the concept of Doze, which further restricts the when/how things can wake up the device.  You can still use exact alarms, but need to use the API which allows it during idle (Doze) time: [`setAndAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).  Bear in mind that when your alarm fires, you could be in a Doze window and your app will be restricted on what kinds of operations it can perform.

Answer (score 1):

Try below for Repeating alarm on every 20 minutes interval

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android worker manager since it is working with doze mode as well. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#min_periodic_interval_millis

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest